# Accessing outlook contact lists in Matlab.

Tags: matlab, outlook, contacts

I'm trying to use Matlab to add contacts to a specific contact list in Outlook.
I can create new contacts using this:

```
h = actxserver('outlook.Application');

newContact = h.CreateItem('olContactItem');
newContact.FirstName = 'John';
newContact.LastName = 'Smith';
newContact.Email1Address = 'john.smith@email.email';
newContact.Save();

% newContact.Display;  % To check your work
h.release;  % Close the ActiveX interface
```

However, this method will add the contact to my first email-account. I wish to be able to specify to what account the contacts are saved, and to what contact group.

I've looked around in [Outlook's object model reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208225(v=office.12).aspx) and found a few promising things like `AdressLists` but i've not been able to figure out how i can get this to work.

Comment: "first email-account" as in "the default store in the profile"? Or as in "I want a different contact folder in the same store where my default Contacts folder is located"?

Comment: I'm signed into two emails when i open Outlook. There's my account for mitchell@private.com and mitchell@work.com. If i use the method above the contact will be stored in the default contacts folder on the first email, that is mitchell@private.com I wish to specify that the contact should be saved to mitchell@work.com and that it is not saved in the default contact folder, but in a specific contact group.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `Application.CreateItem`, retrieve the appropriate store from the `Application.Session.Stores` collection and call `Store.GetDefaultFolder`. Once you have the Contacts folder from the secondary store, call `MAPIFolder.Items.Add`.